# PHP Warning : imagewebp(): Palette image not supported by webp

Tags: php, webp

I am trying to create webp images from jpeg and png images using PHP but I have several errors like:
**Warning: imagewebp(): Palette image not supported by webp in /var/www/html/img/**

I have consulted the resource [Fatal error: Paletter image not supported by webp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292617) but unless I am mistaken, it seems to me that I have already applied these recommendations.

Here is my function :

```
        function convertToWebP($url) {
    
        $extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $lstat = lstat($url);
        $mtime = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $lstat['mtime']);
    
        switch ($extension) {
            case 'jpeg' :
            case 'jpg' :
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
                break;
    
            case 'png' :
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($url);
                imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
                imagealphablending($image, true);
                imagesavealpha($image, true);
                break;
    
            case 'gif' :
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($url);
                break;
    
            default : 
                return false;
            }
    
            imagewebp($image, 'php.webp', 80);
            imagedestroy($image);
}
```

I would be very grateful to have some help

PHP 7.4.3
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Tried the code myself and had no issues until I tried to convert a `.gif`, adding the `imagepalettetotruecolor` function call to that solved the error for me. The solution seems to be to make sure your images are converted to true colors before you try and convert the image to a `.webp` file.

Comment: It actually works ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Kim Hallberg's comment, I found the solution. it was enough to add the `imagepalettetotruecolor` function to convert the `.gif` files as well.